# Cannot convert value JSON to AnyObject in Alamofire and Sync

Tags: json, swift

I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to call and API and get back a JSON response. I am then using:

```
let responseJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
let userDataJSON = responseJSON["userData"]

Sync.changes(
   userDataJSON,
   inEntityNamed: "User",
   dataStack: self.appDelegate.dataStack,
   completion: { (response ) -> Void in
      print("User \(response)")
})
```

to try to Sync the response to Core Data using Hyperoslo Sync but I am getting an error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type '[AnyObject]!'
```

Thanks

EDIT

```
Alamofire.request(Router.AuthenticateUser(postParameters))
   .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
   .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
   .responseJSON { response in
       if response.result.isSuccess {
          let responseJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
          if let userDataJSON = responseJSON["userData"] {
             Sync.changes(
                [userDataJSON],
                inEntityNamed: "User",
                dataStack: self.appDelegate.dataStack,
                completion: { (response ) -> Void in
                    print("User \(response)")
                })
           }
...

Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSON'
```

Comment: I have little insight into snippet or SwiftyJSON, but isn't JSON a dictionary and not an array?

Comment: Your userDataJSON is not an array you need to pass argument like [userDataJSON] and just check if userDataJSON is an optional then safely unwrap it using either if let or force unwrap (!) i.e. [userDataJSON]!

Answer (score -1):

As per documentation Sync.changes syntax:

```
Sync.changes(
  changes: [AnyObject]!,
  inEntityNamed: String!,
  dataStack: DATAStack!,
  completion: ((NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

It expect array of AnyObject, and you are passing just userDataJSON which is not an array so pass it like [userDataJSON].
Also check if userDataJSON is an optional then either safely unwrap using if let or force unwrap using ([userDataJSON]!).

So try,

```
Sync.changes(
   [userDataJSON]!,
   inEntityNamed: "User",
   dataStack: self.appDelegate.dataStack,
   completion: { (response ) -> Void in
      print("User \(response)")
})
```

or

```
if let userDataJSON = responseJSON["userData"] {
Sync.changes(
       [userDataJSON],
       inEntityNamed: "User",
       dataStack: self.appDelegate.dataStack,
       completion: { (response ) -> Void in
          print("User \(response)")
    })
}
```

Comment: hi, not sure what I am doing wrong but I now get "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSON'" error

Comment: Use the last call without ! (force unwrap) coz your userDataJSON is not an optional.

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning this stuff and can't find clear documentation on it. I have added my entire Alamofire code above.